# Error when trying to use pymysql with sqlalchemy sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pymysql

I tried to use pymsql with sqlalchemy using this code :

```
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    engine = create_engine("mysql+pymsql://root:@localhost/pydb")
    conn = engine.connect()
```

and this exception is raised here is the full stack trace :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\Parser\dal__init__.py", line 3, in 
        engine = create_engine("mysql+pymsql://root:@localhost/pydb")
      File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.9.2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\engine__init__.py", line 344, in create_engine
      File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.9.2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 48, in create
      File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.9.2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\url.py", line 163, in make_url
      File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.9.2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\url.py", line 183, in _parse_rfc1738_args
      File "C:\Python33\lib\re.py", line 214, in compile
        return _compile(pattern, flags)
      File "C:\Python33\lib\re.py", line 281, in _compile
        p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
      File "C:\Python33\lib\sre_compile.py", line 498, in compile
        code = _code(p, flags)
      File "C:\Python33\lib\sre_compile.py", line 483, in _code
        _compile(code, p.data, flags)
      File "C:\Python33\lib\sre_compile.py", line 75, in _compile
        elif _simple(av) and op is not REPEAT:
      File "C:\Python33\lib\sre_compile.py", line 362, in _simple
        raise error("nothing to repeat")
    sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `:` from your connection string after your username. It should instead be `mysql+pymsql://root@localhost/pydb`

Comment: I tried removing it , but the problem remains the same .

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test that first. You're using Python 3.3 and SQLAlchemy 9.2?

Comment: Yes. Can this be related to using these releases ?

Comment: I'm not sure but I'm not getting the same issue on Python 2.7 and SQLAlchemy  9.1 so I"ll have to build a virtualenv to see if I can recreate this.

Answer (score 0):

my working URI for sqlalchemy 0.9.4 and python3.3 is:

```
sqlalchemy.url = mysql+pymysql://user:password@host:port/database?charset=utf8&use_unicode=0
```

I use pymysql instead of pymsql.